# Surface area of parameterized surface (t,s,ts).

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Given the smooth parameterized surface *p* in *R3* defined by *p(t)=(t,s,ts)* (*i.e. f(t,s)=ts*), where *0<=t<1* and *0<=s<=1*, how would one calculate the surface area of *p*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Line integral**

Let $\mathbf{r} : [a,\,b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be an *arc of regular curve*, supporting $\gamma$, and let $f : \mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\mathcal{D} \supset \gamma$, a real function with real values. We say *line integral* of $f$ along $\gamma$ the integral:

$$
\int_{\gamma} f\,\text{d}\mathbf{s} \equiv \int_a^b f(\mathbf{r}(t))\left|\mathbf{r}'(t)\right|\text{d}t\,.
$$

In particular, if $f \equiv 1$ we obtain the *measure* of $\gamma$:

$$
||\gamma|| = \int_a^b \left|\mathbf{r}'(t)\right|\text{d}t\,.
$$

---

**Surface integral**

Let $\mathbf{r} : A \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be a *regular surface*, supporting $\Sigma$, and let $f : \mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\mathcal{D} \supset \Sigma$, a real function with real values. We say *surface integral* of $f$ on $\Sigma$ the integral:

$$
\iint_{\Sigma} f\,\text{d}\mathbf{S} \equiv \iint_A f(\mathbf{r}(u,\,v))\left|\mathbf{r}_u(u,\,v) \land \mathbf{r}_v(u,\,v)\right|\text{d}u\,\text{d}v\,.
$$

In particular, if $f \equiv 1$ we obtain the *measure* of $\Sigma$:

$$
||\Sigma|| = \iint_A \left|\mathbf{r}_u(u,\,v) \land \mathbf{r}_v(u,\,v)\right|\text{d}u\,\text{d}v\,.
$$

---

**Exercise**

Having understood the above, it's sufficient to apply the respective *definition*. In particular, given the surface of support $\Sigma$ and the law $\mathbf{r}(u,\,v) := (u,\,v,\,u\,v)$, with $(u,\,v) \in A := [0,\,1] \times [0,\,1]$, we get:

$$
\begin{aligned}
||\Sigma|| 
& = \iint_A \left|\mathbf{r}_u(u,\,v) \land \mathbf{r}_v(u,\,v)\right|\text{d}u\,\text{d}v \\
& = \int_0^1 \text{d}u \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}\,\text{d}v \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{2+u^2} + \left(1+u^2\right)\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2+u^2}}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}\right)\right)\text{d}u \\
& = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} - \frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{1}{3}\,\log\left(7+4\sqrt{3}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$